# How can we execute multiple commands in a java code by the help of single command line prompt?

Tags: java, cmd

I tried to execute a multiple commands in a single command line prompt. Here i need to hide to directories. I used this command  `"C:\Windows\System32>cacls C:\Users\FSSD\Desktop\test1 /e /c /d %username% & cacls C:\Users\FSSD\Desktop\test3  /e /c /d %username% & cacls C:\Users\FSSD\Desktop\test3 /e /c /d %username%)"`in commad prompt it executed well, when i use this code in my java Program it doesn't work completely. The first command will be executed.

In my java code i used this command like this,

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process process = runtime
                .exec("cmd.exe /c start cacls C:/Users/FSSD/Desktop/test1  /e /c /d %username%) " + "&"+            
                      "  cacls C:/Users/FSSD/Desktop/test2  /e /c /d %username%" +"&"+  
                      "  cacls C:/Users/FSSD/Desktop/test3  /e /c /d %username%");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

in this what mistake i done, else any other possible to achieve this..

Comment: could you post the exception/stacktrace you are getting while you are executing this ?

Comment: there is no exception message in my console, the first cmd (cmd.exe /c start cacls C:/Users/FSSD/Desktop/test1  /e /c /d %username%))only execute

Comment: I don't see the way it's related to Java. Create 1.cmd and paste your command line there, check if it works at all. If it does, there's something with your Java, if it doesn't (most probably), it's **not** a Java-related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put that lengthy command into a `.bat` or `.cmd` file and invoke that file from Java?

Answer (score 1):

```
.exec("cmd.exe /c start cacls C:/Users/FSSD/Desktop/test1  /e /c /d %username%) " + "&"+
______________________________________________________________________________^
```

what is it for? (`%username%)`)